# Variable used in nested function not assigning values

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, scope, nested

I have a function used to collect users who reacted to a message using Discord.js. Currently, I am able to collect all of the individual user IDs inside a nested function, however, when attempting to return the resulting array to the caller it does not work. See code:

```
const getUsersWhoReacted = async (reactionCollection) => {
    //Parse through each reaction to collect the users who reacted with it
    let result = new Array();
    reactionCollection.each(async (reaction) => {
        let users = await reaction.users.fetch();
        users.forEach(user => {
            result.push(user.id);
        });
        console.log(result); // [id1, id2, id3, id4]
    });
    console.log(result); // []
}
```

Is this caused because the nested function is async and the result is being accessed before the nested function finishes running? Or is it because of some variable scope problem? In either one of the cases, what would an appropriate solution be?

Comment: what is `reactionCollection` ? Does  `.each()` expect a _Promise_ to be returned? if so then use a `await` keyword like, `await reactionCollection.each(...`,  And why not you use `for..of` loop? If you looking concurrency, then push you promise to an array (`promises`) , then use `Promise.all(promises)`

Comment: Works fine with `forEach` in place of `each`. https://codesandbox.io/s/workspace-js-4ddep?file=/src/variable.js.

Comment: @DarshnaRekha I tried replacing `each` with `forEach` and in my sample app it did not work the same. Could you explain why it would be any different, though? @Nur `reactionCollection` is a list containing all of the reactions (`ReactionManager` in discordjs docs). `reaction.users.fetch()` does return a Promise.

Comment: @Heinzen: Can you check this - https://codesandbox.io/s/workspace-js-4ddep?file=/src/variable.js? Let me know what is the difference.

Comment: @DarshnaRekha I did check and I replicated the differences (i.e. `[]` instead of Array and all else). The results are just that it replicates the same problem.

Comment: @Heinzen You mean to say that for you still `results` are still empty for the second `console.log`?

Comment: That is correct -- after applying your solution in codesanbox it still results in an empty second `console.log`. I am investigating a `Promisses.all()` solution. I've had partially better results but still unable to get them out of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution after some refactor and with @Nur suggestion.

```
const getMapOfUsersWhoReacted = async (reactionCollection) => {
    const results = []
    for (const reaction of reactionCollection.array()) {
        results.push(...(await reaction.users.fetch()).keys())
    }
    console.log(`Found IDs: ${results}`);
    return results;
}
```